# Magento Print Order Details gives white screen of death

Tags: php, magento, printing

For some reason I am getting the white screen of death when I try to print an order from the frontend of my Magento store.

If you go to: www.mymagentostore.com/sales/order/print/order_id/1/

It simply takes me to an blank pages, no source code.

I checked the server and php logs and nothing is displayed.

Any ideas? I am not sure where to look?

Thanks!

Chuck

Comment: What's the HTTP status code? You can find it in the Web Inspector/Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess based on the available information is that you're running out of PHP memory.   If you have access to your server's php.ini or a custom php.ini in your webroot then you can increase your memory limit by adding `memory_limit = 256M;`

You can also try adding it to your `.htaccess` file by adding the following line:

`php_value memory_limit 256M`